# How to return a concrete type when implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface that will be implemented by several different classes, each using different types and return types. The return type can be inferred from the method generic type, but I'm having trouble implementing this.

The interface looks like this currently:

```
public interface TransformUtilsBase<T> {

    Class<?> transformToNhin(T request, BrokerContext brokerContext);
}
```

I want the Impl class to look like:

```
public class TransformUtilsXCPD implements TransformUtilsBase<foo> {

    bar transformToNhin(foo request, BrokerContext brokerContext) {
        code here
    }
```

In the impl I *know* what the return type should be. At the interface level there is no way to tell.

I could just forego an interface all together, and just make several classes all with the same method names, but I wanted to formalize it, since they are all getting used for the same purpose. Only the types are different.

Or I could just have one big class of static methods since they are util operations, but it was becoming unwieldy to manage a class with so many methods with the same name, and all the necessary helper methods (again all with the same name).

Implementing an interface seems like the best option to formalize functionality, even though I'm not able to do static methods. I just can't figure out how to deal with the return types.

edit: expanding on interface to show the full example to prevent further confusion.
Interface

```
public interface TransformUtilsBase<T, U> {
    Class<?> transformToNhin(T request, BrokerContext brokerContext);
    Class<?> transformToXca(U request, BrokerContext brokerContext);
}
```

Impl

```
public class TransformUtilsXCPD implements TransformUtilsBase<Foo, Bar> {
    Baz transformToNhin(Foo request, BrokerContext brokerContext) { code here }
    Biz transformToXca(Bar request, BrokerContext brokerContext) { code here }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return the actual Baz class, or an instance of Baz? Your edit implies it might be the second.

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to return a specific instance of the Baz class, created during the transform process. Wildcard notation is the best way I knew to convey my desired intention to provide generics only for the method variables, which the return type can be determined by.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

why don't you declare the type for the return type as well, something like this

```
public interface TransformUtilsBase<T, S> {

    S transformToNhin(T request, BrokerContext brokerContext);
}
```

you can even "bind" your return type to be of specific type (say `Bar`)

```
public interface TransformUtilsBase<T, S extends Bar> {

    S transformToNhin(T request, BrokerContext brokerContext);
}
```

and the classes who implement will declare as

```
public class TransformUtilsXCPD implements TransformUtilsBase<Foo, BarImpl> {

    BarImpl transformToNhin(Foo request, BrokerContext brokerContext) {
        //code here
    }
}
```

where `BarImpl` is an subclass of `Bar`

Comment: Nitpick: the `S extends Class` part doesn't really make sense with the final example, since `Bar` certainly can't extend `Class`. I would just use something besides `Class` as an example upper bound - I think the OP was confused when he wrote that.

Comment: thanks @PaulBellora i have removed the `Class` as upper bound and given some other example

Comment: I should apologize. I had submitted a shortened version of the interface/impl trying to more concise, but I was not. I had thought of this option, but it just seems unwieldy as I would have 4 generic types. I will create an edit to display the full version. If this is still the best method, than I will use it and mark your answer as correct. Thank you so much for the insight.